# Notice: Undefined index: name in

Tags: php, google-analytics, prestashop1.7

Resulta que no me funcionaba el modulo google analytic instalado en mi prestashop 1.7.6.3 y lo desistale y volvi a instalar, volvi a colocar el codigo de seguimiento y perfecto, empezo a funcionar y a mandar datos a mi cuenta de google analytics, el problema es que ahora me salen unos textos de error en todas las fichas de mis productos donde lo ven los clientes, es el siguiente error:

Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/solamaza0/www/modules/ganalytics/ganalytics.php on line 530
Notice: Undefined index: category in /home/solamaza0/www/modules/ganalytics/ganalytics.php on line 531
Notice: Undefined index: price in /home/solamaza0/www/modules/ganalytics/ganalytics.php on line 539

Actualmente yo entre a esas lineas (de la 530 a la 539) del archivo ganaliytics.php y lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
'name' => Tools::jsonEncode($product['name']),
            'category' => Tools::jsonEncode($product['category']),
            'brand' => isset($product['manufacturer_name']) ? Tools::jsonEncode($product['manufacturer_name']) : '',
            'variant' => Tools::jsonEncode($variant),
            'type' => $product_type,
            'position' => $index ? $index : '0',
            'quantity' => $product_qty,
            'list' => Tools::getValue('controller'),
            'url' => isset($product['link']) ? urlencode($product['link']) : '',
```

No se que configuracion poner para que se me quite este error, podriais ayudarme por favor??
Gracias de antemano
SALUDOS

Answer (score 0):

Si estas viendo esos NOTICE es posible que tengas el modo debug activado, ve a:
parametros avanzados -> rendimiento -> modo depuracion y dejalo en NO

Comment: ¿Quiza seria mejor buscar que causa las notificaciones en lugar de solo ignorarlas no crees?